# mapping a button to sequence of buttons

Tags: vim, vi, macvim

I want to map `tab` to the following button sequence: `ctrl+x` -> `tab` to a method call in .vimrc (in insert mode). The method is also in .vimrc

I kwow i should use `inoremap <tab> button-sequence=method()<CR>`

But how should I write the button sequence in the row above?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question but this is how you'd map `<Tab>` to execute `function()` in *insert* mode.

```
inoremap <Tab> :call function()<CR>
```

***edit***

I had to double check because I didn't know that `<C-x><Tab>` thing. It turns out that the real mapping is `<C-x><C-i>`: `:h i_ctrl-x_ctrl-i`. `<Tab>` and `<C-i>` represent the same character from the terminal's (and Vim's) standpoint.

So… this is what you want, even if mapping `<Tab>` to anything other than `<Tab>` in *insert* mode seems rather silly to me:

```
inoremap <Tab> <C-x><C-i>
```

See `:h key-notation` and `:h mapping`.

Comment: I also want to map `<tab>` to `ctrl-x + <tab>` button combination. So in place of pushin ctrl-x and tab each time I want to only push tab.